# How to pass the JSON validation of write-manifest.json when adding "debugLocale"?

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

I'm trying to build my first **localised** SPFX WebPart for Sharepoint Online. I've added an additional language `de-de.js` in the `loc` folder and now I'm trying to change the `write-manifest.json` to use my new language on debug by adding the `"debugLocale" property to it:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/write-manifests.schema.json",
    "cdnBasePath": "<!-- PATH TO CDN -->",
    "debugLocale": "de-de"
}
```

Checking the [official instructions of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/localize-web-parts) and inspecting the [JSON sheme of the write-manifest.json](https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/write-manifests.schema.json) shows this should compile, but when I `gulp serve` it returns:

```
Build target: DEBUG
./node_modules/@microsoft/node-core-library/lib/JsonSchema.js:178
            throw new Error(prefix + os.EOL +
            ^

    Error: JSON validation failed:
    ./config/write-manifests.json

    Error: #/ (Defines configuration options for the...)
           Additional properties not allowed: debugLocale
        at validateObjectWithCallback (./node_modules/@microsoft/node-core-library/lib/JsonSchema.js:178:19)
        at JsonSchema.validateObjectWithCallback (./node_modules/@microsoft/node-core-library/lib/JsonSchema.js:193:13)
        at JsonSchema.validateObject (./node_modules/@microsoft/node-core-library/lib/JsonSchema.js:175:14)
        at WriteManifestsTask._readConfigFile (./node_modules/@microsoft/gulp-core-build/lib/tasks/GulpTask.js:311:28)
        at WriteManifestsTask.onRegister (./node_modules/@microsoft/gulp-core-build/lib/tasks/GulpTask.js:87:32)
        at Object.initialize (./node_modules/@microsoft/gulp-core-build/lib/index.js:299:24)
        at SPWebBuildRig.initialize (./node_modules/@microsoft/sp-build-common/lib/BuildRig.js:61:19)
        at SPWebBuildRig.initialize (./node_modules/@microsoft/sp-build-common/lib/SPBuildRig.js:29:15)
        at SPWebBuildRig.initialize (./node_modules/@microsoft/sp-build-web/lib/SPWebBuildRig.js:15:15)
        at Object.exports.initialize (./node_modules/@microsoft/sp-build-web/lib/index.js:23:17)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! hello-world@0.0.1 start: `gulp serve`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world@0.0.1 start script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     ~/.npm/_logs/2019-01-09T16_43_53_070Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Between 1.5 and 1.6, the build tasks appeared to have changed. I have confirmed the issue with 1.6+.

If you modify your write-manfiest.json "debugLocale" to "buildSingleLocale", everything will work as expected.  I think the docs and the schema may be out of date.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/write-manifests.schema.json",
    "cdnBasePath": "<!-- PATH TO CDN -->",
    "buildSingleLocale": "de-de"
}
```

Comment: will "buildSingleLocale" act the same as "debugLocale". For me it sounds like "debugLocale" will be ignored on deploying, while "buildSingleLocale" does not.

Comment: I looked at the code base and compared 1.5 to 1.6. Small changes were made determining default vs debug locales. But as it pertained to the debugLocale from the config, it really just looks like debugLocale was switched to buildSingleLocale.

I tested and it worked as expected for me.

Comment: "buildSingleLocale" seem to work for the localised files in the `loc` folder. However, the localised entries in the `.manifest.json` will be ignored (i.e. title and description of the WebPart) as well as there is a warning "Property buildSingleLocale is not allowed."

Comment: If you are talking about in the workbench, this is true. The workbench doesn't support the localized entries in the webpart.manifest.json file. As for the schema, correct, this value is missing from the manifest schema, so you'll have this warning.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried that and it works in my setup.

1. Created webpart using `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` with default options (using React as Javascript framework)
2. Added `de-de.js` file to `loc` folder and changed values so I can see that is really grabs the correct file
3. Added `"debugLocale": "de-de"` to `write-manifests.json`
4. Run `gulp serve`
5. Texts used are from `de-de.js`

My versions:

- yo - 2.0.3
- @microsoft/sharepoint generator - 1.4.1 (I know it is old one)
- npm - 5.6.0 (Yes, also old one)

**But**, once I update the `@microsoft/sharepoint` generator to latest version 1.7.1 it stopped working. It seems that the issue occurs since version 1.6.0

Workaround is to run it with `--locale` parameter like `gulp serve --locale=de-de` or to use older version:

```
npm uninstall @microsoft/generator-sharepoint -g
npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.5.1 -g
```

Comment: Thanks for redirecting the issue to MS.

Comment: @modiX if it was helpful, please accept it as answer.